# sharepoint 2013 usage report not showing latest data

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-analytics

we have restored a farm backup on new environment. Then we created new search service application. The application is working fine. However the Usage report is not showing updated data. Since last 2 days multiple unique users have access the site. But the count is 0 since last 2 days.

Google for this but every where getting links for data itself not showing. Howver in our case it has stopped showing latest data.

Answer (score 0):

For the 0 value, please go to CA->manage service application to check if Search service application and Health and Usage data collection are running and they have been properly configured.

Here is a link for troubleshooting:
http://blog.fpweb.net/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-web-analytics/#.VpYOP2bUh_9

reference link
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8bdb3c1-a1c1-4734-a929-15f80ce5f7e1/usage-reports-in-sharepoint-2013-how-many-concurrent-logins-daily-average-concurrent-logins-daily?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: Hi Adil, Thanks for your reply. have gone through the complete steps mentioned in link. They all are in place. Data getting logged in WSS_UsageApplication database. However, when i export report it is not showing data. What could i be missing.

Comment: please check the uls logs and share if you found anything